# How to run grunt-init from a Grunt task?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-init

I am either blanking out or it is more complex that it should have been.

I am trying to run `grunt-init` from a Grunt task, something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Scaffold various artifacts', function(param) {
  // analyze `param` and pass execution to `grunt-init`
  // run `grunt-init path/to/some/template/based/on/param/value`
});
```

The part of analysis of the `param` is, of course, not the issue. It's running the `grunt-init` that is.

**Running `grunt-init` directly in the same folder as the below attempts works fine**.

I've tried the following methods (path to template is inlined for shortness of the code), all to no avail:

#### grunt-shell

```
shell: {
    init: {
        options: { 
            stdout: true,
            callback: function(err, stdout, stderr, cb) {
                ...
            }
        },
        command: 'grunt-init path/to/some/template/based/on/param/value'
    }
}
```

and then:

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Scaffold various artifacts', function(param) {
    grunt.task.run(['shell:init']);
});
```

and in command line:

```
grunt init
```

or from command line directly:

```
grunt shell:init
```

#### grunt-exec

```
exec: {
    init: {
        cmd: 'grunt-init path/to/some/template/based/on/param/value',
        callback: function() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Scaffold various artifacts', function(param) {
    grunt.task.run(['exec:init']);
});
```

and in command line:

```
grunt init
```

or from command line directly:

```
grunt exec:init
```

#### Node's `exec`

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Scaffold various artifacts', function(param) {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('grunt-init path/to/some/template/based/on/param/value', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        ...
    });
});
```

and in command line:

```
grunt init
```

**Nothing.**

There were various attempts, best of which would print the first line of `grunt-init` prompt:

```
Running "init" task
```

And that's it.

**What am I missing? Should I have connected the `stdout` somehow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way, but it feels hack-ish to me. I am going to answer this, but, **please** give yours too.

It can be done using [grunt-parallel](https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-parallel)

#### grunt-parallel

where task is defined using:

```
parallel: {
    init: {
        options: {
            stream: true
        },
        tasks: [
            {cmd: 'grunt-init'}
        ]
    }            
}
```

and `init` task is:

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Scaffold various artifacts', function(param) {
    // calculate path based on `param`
    ...
    grunt.config.set('parallel.init.tasks.0.args', ['path/to/some/template/based/on/param/value']);
    grunt.task.run(['parallel:init']);
});
```

then, running the following in command line:

```
grunt init:<some param indicating template type or similar>
```

properly runs `grunt-init`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a child process with [grunt.util.spawn](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util). You can make it asynchronous and set stdio to 'inherit' so that any template prompts can be answered. Also, you should set a cwd or else it will try to overwrite your existing Gruntfile.js!

```
grunt.registerTask('init', 'Scaffold various artifacts', function(grunt_init_template) {

    var done = this.async();

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'grunt-init',
        args: [grunt_init_template],
        opts: {
            stdio: 'inherit',
            cwd: 'new_project_dir',
        }
    }, function (err, result, code) {
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this better because it does not require any extra modules, and works well.